# How to save without locking all the tables on grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, cascade

I have this domain class which is using another domain class as property `city`:

```
class Tracker
{
    String name, value;
    City city;
    int hits;
    Date date;
}
```

And I insert or update values using `Tracker.save();` in a long job procedure.

That is working fine except when I want to update something on the city domain class while the tracker is saving something. And it says `Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

I don't make changes in city when saving tracker, but I think hibernate thinks I do and lock city domain too.

Answer (score 0):

Try `tracker.save(flush: true)`
or flush the session after your updates:

```
def sessionFactory
sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Tracker
{
    String name, value;
    City city;
    int hits;
    Date date;

    static mapping = {
        city cascade: "delete"
    }
}
```

This will only `cascade delete`; this should do, as you said, you don't make changes to `city` when saving `tracker`.

**Note:** Also have a look at `cascade evict`.